# Has been or had been

Tags: past-participles

Which one is correct?

1. he is not in this photo as he has been the photographer. or
2. He is not not in this photo as he had been the photographer.

Lets say it's been so many years since that particular event had been there. But the photographer is still among us. May be one of our friends who is conversing with us when the above sentences are said as dialogues.

Comment: This does not call for *have* plus a participle.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for: "He is not in the photo, as he **was** the photographer."